# Update mysql database specific field with this bash script

Tags: bash, mysql

I am using the following bash script to update an email address "currentemail@email.com" but the problem I have is that the field could be anything, not necessary "currentemail@email.com" I have tried to use '*' instead, how can I run the following to work for whatever the current email is set as under "emailaddress" field?

```
#! bin/bash
updatevar="UPDATE email_users SET emailaddress = REPLACE(emailaddress, 'currentemail@email.com', 'admin@$(hostname)');"

mysql --user=root --password=PASSWORD DATABASE << eof
$updatevar
eof
```

Comment: This is a DB/query question, this might be posted in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question well, you want to replace all email addresses on the database, right? In that case, use the following:

```
updatevar="UPDATE email_users SET emailaddress = 'admin@$(hostname)';"
```

Comment: This would set the email address of all users. We don't have enough information about the schema or data to determine how to update the correct row in the `email_users` table.